# How do I disable mob despawn entirely in 1.7.10 and/or 1.6.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want my players to be unable to log out to clear chunks from hostile mobs and not having to bother about disappearing pets. So I would like to be able to disable despawn mechanics entirely in those two versions, better in 1.7.10.

Any way to do this?

Comment: I'm sure there's a plugin for this if you're running Bukkit &c, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Even if it were possible in vanilla, this would break the server. Mobs not despawning can easily kill a server with lag.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Not really; as far as I know, there are caps, and unless something goes wrong, mobs don't spawn in huge hordes.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy The cap is per-player and additive, so it get can really, really high. Besides, the *only* way they ever go away is by despawning (or being killed), so disabling despawning would result in either a) crashing due to Out of Memory errors, b) the cap preventing mobs from ever spawning anywhere else in the world ever again. Even if it doesn't crash, mobs eat a lot of RAM, which causes lag long before crashes start. And it would become part of the save, possibly making it un-recoverable. This is an easy mod to write, but it's a really bad idea.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Didn't think it happens even if the chunk with a mob isn't loaded... Any custom spawning plugins to possible fight the issue?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy That would be turning this into a recommendation request, which are off topic here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie So, not allowed to ask for a plugin solution?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the only way to prevent mobs from despawning is to either remain near them at all times or assigning them a name with a name tag.

If you're only concerned about players losing their pets, then I would recommend possibly distributing name tags to everyone and they can name whatever mobs they would like to make sure won't disappear.

Comment: put a command saying "entitydata @e PersistanceRequired:1" im not too sure about this tho

Comment: @HarounMohamed-Fakier That's the way to manually make a mob not a subject to despawn. Any way to make it automatically applied to every mob of a certain type?

Comment: I think, I will give away name tags, but the problem with clearing chunks of hostile mobs still persists, players may choose not to fight mobs and clear a chunk by relogging.

Comment: What do you mean by automatic?

Comment: like a repeating command block set to allways active with the setector @e[type=Wolf]